# NFC/RFID module multiple cards

Tags: esp8266, rfid, nodemcu

I have [this NFC module](https://www.itead.cc/wiki/RDM8800). When i read ONE card at a moment everything works fine, but i need to read more that one cart at a moment.

One card lays on a module - module reads it ok, when I move another card over modure, I get a mix of both card's numbers.

Is there any way to read both card at one moment correctry?

I read card like this. As a bord I use [NodeMCU ESP8266 ESP-12E](https://www.banggood.com/Geekcreit-Doit-NodeMcu-Lua-ESP8266-ESP-12E-WIFI-Development-Board-p-985891.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc_elc&utm_campaign=ds-led1-solar&utm_content=serene&gclid=Cj0KCQiAi7XQBRDnARIsANeLIesrLDI5NXD42oupeg1A9Wq8TQsvMmrNG9YAHyYcfu8siVgkCFapJf8aAk5JEALw_wcB)

```
SoftwareSerial rfid(RFID_RX, RFID_TX);
..
void loop()
{
    rfid.listen();
    delay(500);

    while (rfid.available() > 0) {
        Serial.println("Closest card number: " + rfid.readString());
    }

}
```

Comment: "*at a moment*"? Do you mean that you want to read two cards simultaneously at the same time?

Comment: @gre_gor, yes, at same time. in perspective I need to read about 4-5 cards at one moment